# Image in javaFx Listview shows only when is selected

Tags: java, image, listview, javafx

i want to make a listview with an image, some text and a button pro column, but the image is only displayed when the column is selected(clicked). But i want the images/icons to be displayed independ from beeing selected/clicked...

```
todoView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoView>, ListCell<TodoView>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TodoView> call(ListView<TodoView> todoViewListView) {
           ListCell<TodoView> cell = new ListCell<>() {
               @Override
               protected void updateItem(TodoView item, boolean empty) {
                   super.updateItem(item, empty);
                   if (item != null) {
                       setGraphic(item);
                   }
               }
           };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

(TodoView)item obj is an hbox with imageview, label and button...
any ideas?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: That's not much code. We can't write your app for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your `ListView`, you should really be specifying your object model, not a Node (`TodoView`) in your case.

You can define your layout and how you want each `ListView` cell to look within the `setCellFactory` method instead. This allows you greater control over each item and follows a more appropriate separation of concerns (keeping your data model separate from your UI).

I've used the idea of a book store for this example, but you'll see that it allows you to have complete control over the layout of each cell:

[image: screenshot]

---

**The Code:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewCustomObjects extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create a simple layout
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        // Create a list of Books
        ObservableList<Book> booksList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        booksList.addAll(
                new Book("Where the Red Fern Grows", new Image("Controls/ListView/img/fern.jpg")),
                new Book("Hatchet", new Image("Controls/ListView/img/hatchet.jpg")),
                new Book("David Copperfield", new Image("Controls/ListView/img/david_copperfield.jpg"))
        );

        // Create our ListView
        ListView<Book> bookListView = new ListView<>();
        bookListView.setItems(booksList);

        // Here we'll create our ListView's CellFactory, which will control how each Book item is displayed.
        bookListView.setCellFactory(cell -> {
            return new ListCell<Book>() {

                // Let's create the HBox layout and elements that will be displayed. The actual values will be
                // updated in the updateItem() method.
                final HBox rootLayout = new HBox(5) {{
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                    setPadding(new Insets(5));

                }};

                // The ImageView for the Book's cover art
                final ImageView cover = new ImageView() {{

                }};

                // Create the Label that will hold the book's title
                final Label title = new Label();

                // The Button we'll include to order the book
                final Button orderButton = new Button("Order Now");

                // This static block allows us to add our elements to the HBox outside of the updateItem() method.
                // We'll add the book's cover
                {
                    rootLayout.getChildren().addAll(cover, title, orderButton);
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Book item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item != null) {

                        // This is where we update our rootLayout HBox to display this specific Book
                        cover.setImage(item.getCover());

                        // Let's just set our image size here
                        cover.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        cover.setFitWidth(50);
                        cover.setFitHeight(100);

                        title.setText(item.getTitle());
                        // Simple onAction() method to print out the book we're purchasing.
                        orderButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                            System.out.println("Ordering \"" + item.getTitle() + "\"!");
                        });

                        // Finally, set this cell's graphic to display the HBox
                        setGraphic(rootLayout);
                    } else {
                        // Not book in this cell, set the graphic to null
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        // Finally, add our ListView to the root VBox
        root.getChildren().add(bookListView);

        // Build and show the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

// Sample data model. For this example, we'll be displaying a list of Books
class Book {

    // Each book will have a title and cover image.
    private final String title;
    private final Image cover;

    public Book(String title, Image cover) {
        this.title = title;
        this.cover = cover;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Image getCover() {
        return cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image still only shows up when the item is selected..The buttons are displayed and the text but image only appears when the item are selected

Comment: @user11998955 Then you're doing something differently. I'd recommend adding the [mcve] as requested.

Comment: i ve copied your exact code and same issue

Comment: What Java version? Are you getting any Exceptions?